# Configuring a Beowulf cluster with Mosix

Tags: linux, cluster

Here's the situation: We're trying to build a Beowulf cluster using Mosix. At first, we're testing everything on VMWare, but we want to deploy it on actual hardware in the near future.

However, it seems that Mosix is VERY poorly documented and we're trying to figure everything out.

This is the current situation: I have 2 virtual Lubuntu's (we tried openSuse and Ubuntu, but those didn't seem to be working at all), each running kernel 3.1.5. I've tried installing mosix with the standard ./mosix.install command that comes with the latest build. This SEEMS to work, but whenever I type /etc/init.d/mosix reload it says the kernel isn't optimised... When I try to "optimise" it using the default intaller it gives me a "./mosix.install: 428: patch: not found. Sorry, failed patching the kernel (is it a wrong version?)" No, it's not a wrong version, it's the 3.1.5 you require....

Anyway, testing it out without optimized kernel then: I type mosconf, enter the IP addresses of all the nodes in the cluster, reload mosix and run mon to see wether something is happening.
Nope, there isn't, I only see 1 Node in the graphic presented... The other one goes undetected.

Long story short: Is there a clear, well documented guide out there that will tell me how to configure mosix? Or does anyone of you know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mosix, really? Are you from the past? :)

Comment: Any specific reason to use Mosix?
Also, if I'm not wrong, the mosix cluster model is not the same as the beowulf cluster model.

Comment: The five latest mosix distributions all date from 2011. Not that much of a past-thing it would seem... Also, it seemed like something we could use in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-mosix/l-mosix-pdf.pdf

=> decent, clear, step-by-step guide.